Передать несколько параметров в Request body
столкнулся с таким вопросом. Есть пут запрос, в Request body должен отправляться вот такой объект
{
"ticketsid": 0,
"firstnum": 0,
"ticketsinvoicenum": "string",
"ticketsinvoicedate": "2024-04-22"
}
Так прописано в swagger
По логике проекта, из таблицы выбирается поле, данные из этого поля я привожу в формат
    async function returnEvent() {
  const data = modalTableData.map(obj => {
    return {
      ticketsid: obj.blanksinvoiceid,
      firstnum: obj.blanksfirstnum,
      ticketsinvoicenum: obj.ticketsinvoicenumber,
      ticketsinvoicedate: obj.blanksinvoicedate.split('T')[0],
    }
  })
  console.log(data)

  try {
    await rest.axios.put('/blanks/return_tickets', data)
  }catch (e) {
    console.log('blanksOnWarehouse || ListView.vue || returnEvent =>', e)
  }
}

но также по логике программы, в таблице можно выбрать несколько полей, какой запрос тогда отправлять на сервер ?

«какой запрос тогда отправлять на сервер ?» — такой, который он ожидает в соответствии со своим кодом и своей документацией. Пока что суть вопроса непонятна

в документации требуется один объект, но если выбрали несколько объект из таблицы, из всех этих объектов надо создать массив с объектами подходящего формата и это массив передавать в запросе ?

Читайте в коде/документации сервера, ожидает ли он принять массив, мы не можем этого знать
